# stay multi drop down page for given time

Tags: javascript, php, html

i designed a drop down and that second level drop down page is **form** now when i want that second level drop down page stay longer , for that i used java script code that is here

```
<script>
var timer;
$(".parent").on("mouseover", function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
    openSubmenu();
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
  timer = setTimeout(
    closeSubmenu
  , 1000);
});

function openSubmenu() {
  $(".submenu").addClass("open");
}
function closeSubmenu() {
  $(".submenu").removeClass("open");
}
</script>
```

And here is code for making multiple drop down

```
<div class="dropdown">
 <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default" data-target="#" style=" padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px;"> Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
  <li><a href="index.php?index_edit_id=<?php echo $c_id;?>"><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm remove" ><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg" aria-hidden='true' style=" font-weight:10px;"> Edit-Update</i></button></a></li>
 <div class="divider"></div>
 <li class="dropdown-submenu parent">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-left" aria-hidden="true"style="padding-left:10px;">Edit-File</i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu submenu">
                     Here is code of form 
                </ul>
              </li>
         </ul>
 </div>
```

and this is css  i am using , i just want when i am drop down from **edit-file** then my drop down page  should stop for given time

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    right: 100%;
    margin-top: -210px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
   display: block;
}
.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float:left;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
   border-left-color: #fff;
}
.multi-level
{
   position:justify;
   right:100%;
   margin-left:-60px;   
}
```

Please help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this...

```
<style>
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    right: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
   display: block;
}
.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float:left;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
   border-left-color: #fff;
}
.multi-level
{
   position:justify;
   right:100%;
}

</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
    <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default" data-target="#" style=" padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px;">Action
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
        <li>
            <a href="index.php?index_edit_id=<?php echo $c_id;?>">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm remove" >
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg" aria-hidden='true' style=" font-weight:10px;"> Edit-Update</i>
                </button>
            </a>
        </li>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu parent">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-left parent" aria-hidden="true"style="padding-left:10px;">Edit-File</i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu submenu">
                <li>
                    <form>
                        <p><input /></p>
                        <p><input /></p>
                        <p><input /></p>
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

   <script>
var timer;
    $(".parent").on("mouseover", function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        openSubmenu();
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
        timer = setTimeout(
            closeSubmenu
        , 1000);
    });

    function openSubmenu() {
        $(".submenu").show();
    }
    function closeSubmenu() {
        $(".submenu").hide();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: here code is running correct but when i copied this code on my page still java script code is not working . is there any alternate solution without using java script . if you do know then help me